TCL file size complexity
The basic problem statement is to check if a file exists. In my flow, the existing code does the following to check for file existence. This part of the code is visited a significant number of times. I also have a switch to force ls on the directory to do the expensive NFS sync up, if required.
proc check_file_exists { filename use_ls } {

    set fexists 1;
    if { ![file exists $filename] } {
        set fexists 0;
        if { $use_ls == 1 } {
            # expensive NFS sync up
            set fileDir [file dirname $filename]
            if { [file exists $fileDir] } {
                ls $fileDir;
                if { [file exists $filename] } {
                    set fexists 1;
                }
            }
        }
        if { $fexists == 0 } {
            puts "File '${filename}' does not exist.";
        }
    }
    return $fexists;
}

The problem however with the above approach is if say for some reason I pass a path (directory only) with no file name, the proc returns a 1 and not 0. So, I modified the code to do this -
proc check_file_exists { filename use_ls } {
    
    set fexists 1;
    set excp [catch {file size $filename} fSize];
    if { ($excp != 0) || ($fSize <= 0)  } {
        set fexists 0;
        if { $use_ls == 1 } {
            # expensive NFS sync up
            set fileDir [file dirname $filename]
            if { [file exists $fileDir] } {
                ls -d $fileDir;
                set excp [catch {file size $filename} fSize];
                if { ($excp == 0) && ($fSize > 0) } {
                    set fexists 1;
                }
            }
        }
        if { $fexists == 0 } {
            puts "File '${filename}' does not exist.";
        }
    }
    return $fexists;
}

How expensive is TCL file size foo. Is it reading from a file descriptor or is it computing size on the fly? Is there a better way to handle the above scenario or problem statement? What is the time complexity of the above two codes for a million file exists check?

why do you need to use ls ? looks superfluous, using "file size $filename" will fail if the file doesn't exist, so just deal with that, if the file needs to be >0 bytes then add that constraint

Why not just test - in order - 'file isdirectory', 'file isfile', 'file exists', with the remaining case indicating the given path doesn't exist. I think that will do it for you. No need to 'ls' or get the file size (it does a 'stat' system call to get the size).

The file size command is a wrapper around the stat() system call (when not on a virtual filesystem, which doesn't apply in your case); it doesn't read the file. On Windows the call to get the file's size is a little different, but works similarly; the size of a file is part of the metadata of the file.
Likewise, file exists uses access() with the F_OK flag (with every caveat associated with that system call). As with stat(), on NFS it should be a single network call to the NFS server. If it isn't enough to determine if a file exists, something is badly misconfigured in the NFS deployment, either in the client or server (though files can be created or deleted by other processes, of course).
